# ROS2 on multiple machines: ros2 multicast working, talker/listener not working

Tags: ubuntu, udp, ros, ros2, ufw

PROBLEM

I have installed ROS 2 foxy on 2 computers and trying to run the demo talker on one machine and the demo listener on the other. Unfortunately it does not work.

However:

- the ros2 multicast test works;
- the talker/listener DO work when I completely disable the firewall.

I would like to know how to configure the firewall (or any other system parameter) so the talker/listener will work without having to completely disable the firewall.

Note that ros2 is installed on the OS directly, not in Docker.

COMPUTERS

Both computers:

- are on the same network (home network with simple router);
- are connected by cables to the router;
- have static IPs;
- run Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (focal).

```
$ lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

FIREWALL: UDP MULTICAST ENABLED

I have configured `ufw` to allow UDP multicast on both machines as per ref. [1] below.

```
$ sudo ufw allow in proto udp to 224.0.0.0/4
Rule added
$ sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 224.0.0.0/4
Rule added
$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 224.0.0.0/4/udp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    224.0.0.0/4/udp           
[ 4] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Following this configuration, I am able to run the ros2 multicast test between both machines.

```
machine1 $ ros2 multicast send
Sending one UDP multicast datagram...

machine2 $ ros2 multicast receive
Waiting for UDP multicast datagram...
Received from 192.168.1.108:34434: 'Hello World!'
```

However, the talker/listener do not hear each other.

```
machine1 $ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
[INFO] [1672838648.074547042] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[INFO] [1672838649.074330969] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'

machine2 $ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
(waits forever...)
```

FIREWALL: DISABLED

By disabling the firewall on both machines, the talker/listener can hear each other.

```
machine1 $ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
machine1 $ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
[INFO] [1672838846.953415499] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 1]
[INFO] [1672838847.953088937] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 2]

machine2 $ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
machine2 $ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
[INFO] [1672838846.944245747] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[INFO] [1672838847.944211861] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
```

QUESTION

How could I configure my firewall (or any other OS parameter) so the talker/listener can see each other without having to disable the firewall?

REFERENCES

[1] https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

All right so the issue was that my firewall was blocking communications between my computers... The issue was solved simply by allowing UDP in on both machines.

```
Machine 1 $ sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24
Machine 2 $ sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24
```

A good practice might be to specify the exact IP of each machine & the exact source/destination ports on each machine, but since these are 2 computers I only use from time to time the rules specified above were OK for me...

NOTE REGARDING `ros2 multicast`

One thing that still bugs me is that, when running on the same machine, `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp` works correctly while `ros2 multicast` does not (`ros2 multicast` requires to `sudo ufw allow in proto udp to/from 224.0.0.0/4` as mentionned [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html)).

By following ignacio's advice and using `wireshark`, I observed that `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp` actually broadcasts to address 239.255.0.1, while `ros2 multicast` broadcasts to 224.0.0.0.

I find it odd that `ros2 multicast` broadcasts to a different address than `ros2 run`, as the goal of `ros2 multicast` is to validate `ros2 run` can send data... This seems to be an incoherence with ROS2. Maybe `ros2 multicast` was developped for an earlier version of ROS2 (before foxy) and is no longer relevant for newer versions? I don't know... And I must admit my knowledge of multicasting is limited.

So for now, I am simply assuming `ros2 multicast` is a tool which should not be used and that the following command must be ran when running ROS2 systems on several machines on the same network.

```
$ sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends which DDS Implementation you are going to use as middleware. `foxy` uses `eProsima` by default. Their manual [eprosima-fast-rtps.pdf](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/eprosima-fast-rtps/latest/eprosima-fast-rtps.pdf) might have the ports that you are looking for.

Maybe you could also use `wireshark` instead to check which ports are used and enable those.

Answer (score 0):

I found `ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY` was set to 1 on my server. It had not been changed since installation (following ROS2 first tutorials it is mentioned and usually added to bash along with `ROS_DOMAIN_ID`). So the solution for me was to unset `ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case: I just need to set `export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp`. I know it is weird since the docs states that eProsima is the default DDS. [Source](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/DDS-Implementations/Working-with-eProsima-Fast-DDS.html)